# Initial state is invalid when Primefaces components under Omnifaces tree

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I use omnifaces tree to edit some recursive data structure.But the primefaces component's state is invalid (has red border) when I open the page.

versions:

- omnifaces-1.3-SNAPSHOT-20121121.jar
- primefaces-3.4.1
- tomee 1.5.1 with myfaces 2.1.9
- java 7

I also tested with Mojarra 2.1.9, the same result.
[Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4606812/testee.zip) is the archive of the eclipse project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by a bug in OmniFaces `EditableValueHolderStateHelper`. The `valid` property indeed incorrectly defaults to `false`. This is reported as [issue 105](http://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/issues/detail?id=105) and a snapshot containing the fix is provided in the issue ticket.

Comment: Thank you @BalusC confirmed it's fixed.